# Moving an object in an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, move

I'm new to Java, and I'm having some trouble moving an object around my array; the thing is: suppose that you have an `X` object in `m[i][j]`, and a Y object in `m[i][j+1]`. What I want is to move `X` to `m[i][j+1]`, show `X` in that position, and then move it to `m[i][j+2]`, and make `Y` object appear back in its original position. Any ideas?

#### edit:

- step 1 should show this: X Y _
- Step 2: _ X _
- Step 3: _ Y X

Comment: What do you mean by "show X in that position"? Do you need to print the array after each move? Where does Y go after the first move?

Comment: You should create a temporary storage for X then move Y to position of X then move X to old position of Y.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman i've tried moving X's m[i][j] to m[i][j+1] and creating a new "_" in X's initial m[i][j], but I can't seem to figure out how to know there was a Y in new X's position.

Comment: @Vash how would i create a temporary storage? you mean like a new variable?

Comment: New variable should do the trick.

Comment: @Vash i'll try it and i'll see the result, thanks

Comment: @Vash tried to do it that way, but I couldn't get it to work properly... Could you create a sample of the code, please?

Comment: I'm not sure that i have undertood your question but this is more less how to switch   int tmp = array[i][j];
   array[i][j] = array[i][j+1];
   array[i][j+1] = tmp;

Answer (score 0):

```
    final Object underScoreObjectWhateverThatIs = null;
    final Object o1 = new Integer(1);
    final Object o2 = new Integer(2);
    final Object o3 = new Integer(3);
    final Object o4 = new Integer(4);
    final Object[][] m = new Object[][]{new Object[]{null, o1}, new Object[]{o1, o2, o3, o4}};
    final int i = 1;
    final int j = 1;
    //Test vars set up
    //Going for step 1;
    m[i][j + 2] = underScoreObjectWhateverThatIs;
    //We now have step one
    Object X = m[i][j];
    Object Y = m[i][j + 1];
    m[i][j] = underScoreObjectWhateverThatIs;
    m[i][j + 1] = X;
    //We now have step 2
    m[i][j + 1] = Y;
    m[i][j + 2] = X;
    //We now have step 3
            // (X was o2, and Y was o3 here if that is unclear)
```

---

That is my best interpretation of what you are describing. This is java code but it screams that there is some bad thinking going on here. For some reason we have arrays of Object arrays, if the reason isn't really good we should probably reconsider writing some class or using Lists/Collections or something. What are you really trying to do? Why are we messing around with arrays?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're effectively dealing with two layers... it's not just simple array manipulation.  You're describing a state where X can be in front of Y in the same space.

You have lots of choices.  You could have an array for X and an array for Y.  As you loop through the elements, you test if X exists then print it, else print whatever is in the Y array.  If X is only one character, it could even be represented by a single integer variable.  Think of the array as only holding Y or underscore, but as you're looping through its elements, if you're on the Xth element, then print "X" instead of the element in the Y array.

Comment: Also, consider what you've recently learned in class in light of your teacher wanting to build on prior concepts.  If your focus has been on string manipulation, then maybe you're meant to store "XY" and display only the X.  If it's bit-masking, then you could take that approach.